# Adding file:// at the beginning of a path using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to add `file://` at the beginning of a path using PowerShell. How can I do that? I tried like this:

```powershell
$file = "C://Windows"
$path = Join-Path "file://" $file
```

But is not working.

Comment: this: `$path = "file://$file"`

Answer (score 4):

If you really want the Uri syntax, you can leverage **System.Uri** like:

```
[Uri]$tu = New-Object 'Uri'('C:\Windows');
write-host $tu.AbsoluteUri;
```

That will produce a URI output that looks like:

```
file:///C:/Windows
```

(and yes, that third '/' is supposed to be there after the file:.  [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) specifies that there's room for an optional *host* component in the uri: `file://<host>/<path>`)

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = "file://" + $file
```

Also you don' need to escape forward slash in Powershell so `$file` can be `$file="C:/Windows"`